# fetching multiple fields from multiple collections from mongodb-nodejs driver on the basis of array elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I need to fetch data from from mongodb with respect to array elements which i will get in req.body
Description:
**POSTMAN REQUEST** there **can be more than 10 mappedVendors also**

```
    {
    "_id": "5e2554ec3405363bc4bf86c0",
     "mappedVendors": [
                "5e2555783405363bc4bf86c5",
                "5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4",
                "5e2555643405363bc4bf86c8"
    ]}
```

**collection 1 : masters**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5e2554ec3405363bc4bf86c0"),
        "mappedVendors" : [
                ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c5"),
                ObjectId("5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4"),
                ObjectId("5e2555643405363bc4bf86c9")
       "phoneNo" : 9082625539,
        "name" : "dealer 2",
        "address" : "dealer address 2",
        "depotCode" : "D3137",
        "state" : "Tamilnadu",
        "city" : "chennai",
```

**NOTE: deatils of mappedVendors for e.g: ObjectId("5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4") is in the same masters collection**

**collection 2 : orders**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5e2848e309b2ad1b4c5d994c"),
        "isApproved" : false,
"orderCreatedOn" : ISODate("2020-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
"vendorOrder" : [],
"frequency" : "WE",
"orderCreatedBy" : ObjectId("5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4"),
```

**Collection 3: payments**

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5dd78e6c8f2683327c1e26e1"),
 "paymentOfTheDay" : 2200,
 "outstanding" : 300,
 "paymentDoneBy":ObjectId("5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4")
```

scenario is :
i will get mappedVendors array in req.body it can be many and with respect to each mappedVendor
i need to fetch these mentioned fields:**"phoneNo","name","address","depotCode" from masters collection + "isApproved" from orders collection + "outstanding" from payments collection** than i need to send all this **data in an array object ** to the frontend for each and every mappedVendors

```
"vendorListDetails":[{
"phoneNo","name","address","depotCode" ,"isApproved","outstanding"
}]
```

Comment: What's the use of `dealerId` in the request ?

Comment: i have edited my question please check @user3302146 and help me out how to achieve this